# Markov property when the state space is countable

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Let $E$ be a countable space and $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ an $E$-valued stochastic process. Let $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be the filtration generated by the $X_n$'s. Define **property 1** as $$\forall A\in \mathcal B(E), \forall n\leq m, P(X_m\in A| \mathcal F_n) = P(X_m\in A|X_n)$$
>   and **property 2** as: for all $m$,for all $q$, all $p_1<\ldots<p_q<m$, and all $ e_0,e_1,\ldots, e_q\in E$ such that $ P(X_{p_1}=e_1\cap\ldots\cap X_{p_q}=e_q)>0$, then $$P(X_m=e_0|X_{p_1}=e_1\cap\ldots\cap X_{p_q}=e_q) = P(X_m=e_0|X_{p_q}=e_q)$$
>
> Then property 2 $\implies$ property 1

I'm struggling to prove this. I've tried to follow the path suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180730/markov-property-w-r-t-a-countable-state-space). Consider $n\leq m$. Given $e\in E$, it suffices to prove that $\forall B \in \mathcal F_n, E(1_B 1_{X_m=e}) = E(1_BE(1_{X_m=e}|X_n))$.  It is enough to check this for $$B=(X_{p_1}=e_1)\cap\ldots\cap (X_{p_q}=e_q)$$
where $p_1< \ldots < p_q\leq n$.

This is where I'm stuck:$$\begin{align}
E(1_B 1_{X_m=e}) &= P(X_{p_1}=e_1\cap\ldots\cap X_{p_q}=e_q\cap X_m=e)\\
&= \sum_{a\in E}P(X_{p_1}=e_1\cap\ldots\cap X_{p_q}=e_q\cap X_n = a\cap X_m=e)\\
&= \sum_{a\in E}P(X_m=e |X_{p_1}=e_1\cap\ldots\cap X_n = a)P(X_{p_1}=e_1\cap\ldots\cap X_n = a)\\
&= \sum_{a\in E}P(X_m=e |X_n = a)P(X_{p_1}=e_1\cap\ldots\cap X_n = a)
\end{align}$$
How should I continue ? I don't know how to expand $E(1_BE(1_{X_m=e}|X_n))$ either.

Comment: What does $P(X_m|\ldots)$ mean?

Comment: @Jason That's a typo, I meant $P(X_m = e_0|...)$